# Why go_router needs context?

Tags: flutter, flutter-navigation

As I know `Navigator` needs context because we usually build nested navigation using nested `Navigator` widgets, and we can use closest `Navigator` in context. But why we need context for `GoRouter`? As I understand that's just for dependency injection and we can easily replace context with getIt here. Or not?

Comment: This depends on the design system of the package. go_router uses 'InheritedWidget' so he needs the context  to find the router. There are other packages that don't use context like [qlevar_router](https://github.com/SchabanBo/qlevar_router)

Comment: Do you have a way to inject dependency with get it?

Comment: @Schaban if the rest of my app uses GoRouter can I use another package just for my specific use case?  Which is to route to a specific widget from a listener in main()?

Comment: Here is more deets in my use case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73059450/how-can-i-route-using-gorouter-in-flutter-without-context